# How do I reference a custom class in lib from one of my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I create a file in `lib/` called `toast_mitten.rb`, and in that file I have a class called `ToastMitten`, how do I use that class from my models?

For example, inside a method on the `Comments` class (one of my models), if I try to call `ToastMitten.grasp`, I get an error like `uninitialized constant Comment::ToastMitten`.

The class I created is intended to DRY up some repeated code in both my models and a rake task.

Comment: How have you defined the grasp method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rails 3 doesn't autoload lib

The problem was that `lib` was not being autoloaded. I'm using Rails 3.0.0. Apparently, the Rails team decided to stop autoloading `lib` in Rails 3, as José Valim [says here](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib).

To get it to load, I added this to `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

My colleague tells me that my other options would be:

- Add it to `config/initializers`
- Explicitly `require` it in the model where I want to use it

Answer (score 0):

It should work like that, so if you get an error try to restart the server, or check for typos. It would be helpful if you showed the toast_mitten file